# How do I get tooltips in Chrome to appear in the correct location?

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, high-resolution

Below is a screenshot of a slight problem with the location of the tooltip showing up in the incorrect location (note: the red dot is the approximate location of my cursor, and the location of the tooltip seems to move around some relative to my cursor).  I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348242) issue reported on the Chromium project site, but that was reported back in February, and whatever fix they say they implemented is either not fixing the problem, or has not made it to my version of Chrome.  Having said that, I'm not entirely sure what they are recommending as a fix to begin with.

I believe that this problem is also causing the Windows 8 mode to be nearly unusable on my machine as well (the screen is shrunk down to the upper-left-hand corner, and the right and bottom sides are cropped so I can't access the settings button).

Does anyone here know how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot Example]

**System Info:**

Operating system: Windows 8.1
Screen resolution: 1920x1080
Chrome version: 35.0.1916.27 beta-m